# Issue when building documentation on read the docs

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm currently trying to build documentation for my Sphinx restructured text project on readthedocs.com. The documentation itself is in its own github repository. I have already added the webhook for rtd in the repo on github, but for some reason, after I imported the project, I'm getting the error:

```
This repository doesn't have a valid webhook set up. That means it won't be rebuilt on commits to the repository.
You can resync your webhook to fix this.
```

I tried resyncing the webhook by following the link provided, but when I try to build again, the error still shows up. I think that I have the settings correctly configured so I'm not sure what could be causing the problem. The repository itself is set to private, but I wouldn't think that that would necessarily cause a problem.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm nearly certain it's because your repository is set as private if you're using http://readthedocs.org (the free, community, open source version of ReadTheDocs).

The only privacy options available in the community edition can be found here: https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/privacy.html. These relate to the project showing up on the main build list of recently built documents, on the homepage of ReadTheDocs.

If you're wanting to use a private repository you can attempt a custom install of ReadTheDocs on your own localhost machine or support the commercial ReadTheDocs.com version (more details below).

ReadTheDocs.com for commercial projects have several pricing options and support for different privacy levels as well as other support not included in the community readthedocs.org version.

https://readthedocs.com/features/
https://readthedocs.com/pricing/

The readthedocs.com version includes custom SSL, CDN support, mixed private & public docs, and much more. Check the pricing page above for more info.